# Why is my plot not showing any results?

Tags: matlab

My code is below. The values in `loss` should be calculated for each value of `P`, but I'm not getting any data displayed in my plot.

```
clear all
a = 10;
power = 1010;
d = 0.5;
x = 10;
P = linspace(0,10,100);
loss = (10.*(P).^2)/((P).^2+(x.^2));
%t = 1-loss;
%output=(t.*power);
plot(P,loss)
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: "Please give me a solution." is not a question

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `./` instead of `/` to compute `loss`. The first is [element-wise division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html), which will give you the vector you desire, and the second is [matrix division](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/mrdivide.html), which gives you a scalar result.